# Possible bad code or Rails multi-thread issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm having an issue with the below code frequently in a Rails 4.4, Ruby 2.2 with puma web server application.  This code has excessive if statements just to try and figure out the problem.

We can assume that `assign_coupon()` returns true or false.  When it returns true it creates an association between the review and the coupon, so you can type review.coupon. Before you run `assign_coupon()` or if `assign_coupon()` returns false review.coupon will be nil.

The issue is that `assign_coupon()` is not working and review.coupon is nil, yet the code gets past '`if CouponCodeService.assign_coupon(review)`' and then also passes '`if !review.coupon.nil?`' and is running '`review.approve!`'.

I cannot figure out for the life of me how the code gets passed 2 failing if statements to run '`review.approve!`'.  This should not be possible.

```
if review.product.has_coupon_codes?
    if CouponCodeService.assign_coupon(review) # this is false
        if !review.coupon.nil? # this is false
            review.approve! # this is some how executed.
            success_message(review)
            review.send_reviewer_approved_email
        else
            review.update(aasm_state: 'requested')
            error_message(review)
        end
    else
        review.update(aasm_state: 'requested')
        error_message(review)
    end
end




def self.assign_coupon(review)
    begin
      product = review.product
      if product.has_coupon_codes?
        coupon = product.coupons.where(claimed: false).first
        coupon.review_id = review.id
        coupon.claimed = true
        if coupon.save
          return true
        else
          return false
        end
      else
        return false
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      return false
    end
  end
```

Comment: Probably you want to `puts CouponCodeService.assign_coupon(review)` and `puts !review.coupon.nil?` and see if it is actually false.

Comment: Well the end result is review.coupon.nil? is true and yet review.aasm_state = 'approved  This shouldn't be possible.

Comment: There is also a rails validation:
validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :product_id, message: "You can only review a product once"}

And a unique index on the database.

Comment: I have doubts this code is getting executed.  Try `raise CouponCodeService.assign_coupon(review).inspect` and `raise review.coupon.inspect` in these places along your execution path to make sure that: a. this code is even where `review.approve!` is running, and b, to check what you're getting back for `review.coupon` if it's not nil.  If you're having trouble replicating then make sure you're not running your servers multithreaded (don't run multithreaded unless you know what you're doing -- the variable assignment hints this is not).  Finally remember that a `False` object *is not nil.*

Comment: This is the type of thing automated tests are really good at catching. I'd highly recommend building out a few tests for your different branches of business logic. I don't see how this could be a threading issue (note Rails is thread safe and this code doesn't seem to share any state; maybe that where statement)